# Exclusive access to a file

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open file in exclusive mode in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685135/open-file-in-exclusive-mode-in-c-sharp)

There is a file my app sometimes need to read from. An app must be sure that no one is using it before it start using it. And while it (app) using it, no one can modify it (or even read from it).

How can I do it?

Comment: Set the appropriate sharing flags when opening the `FileStream`.

Comment: Duplicate! See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/685135/29555